# Better way to write "I Ran or Walked one hour every morning"

Tags: grammar, verbs

Is there a word to describe the action that involves both running and walking?

Another example

> I reached the destination by walk and sometimes running during the
> Journey.

Comment: "I reached the destination by *walking* and sometimes running ..."

Comment: I walked - and at times ran - to the journey's destination.

Comment: I know you are new here but truly, in your own language are there substitute words for common human activity of walking and running? Your question just seems a tad silly to me.

Comment: @lambie. My language tamil has a word for it. We call it nadaiottam.

Comment: Do you mean that sometimes you reached it by running and sometimes you reached it by walking, or do you mean that you reached it through a combination of running and walking?

Comment: @Davo combination of running and walking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**interval training**

The name for that is "interval training."

[Interval training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_training) can refer to the organization of any cardiovascular workout (e.g., cycling, running, rowing), **but is particularly employed by runners, alternating between running and walking or slow jogging.**

Interval training is a type of training that involves a series of high intensity workouts interspersed with rest or relief periods. The high-intensity periods are typically at or close to anaerobic exercise, while the recovery periods involve activity of lower intensity. Varying the intensity of effort exercises the heart muscle, providing a cardiovascular workout, improving aerobic capacity and permitting the person to exercise for longer and/or at more intense levels.

Many would understand you if you say:

> "I interval train one hour every morning."

"Interval training" is pretty commonly understood because of the *interval training* mode found on nearly all treadmills that alternates the user between running and walking. However, if someone doesn't understand it, they can then ask you what that entails, or if you think they might not understand it, you could teach them what it means by being more elaborative and saying something like:

> "I interval train one hour every morning, which involves alternating
> between running to build heart strength, muscle tone, and stamina and walking to burn fat and lower my BMI."

Comment: This does not correspond to his sentences at all...

Comment: @Lambie- How so? He asked for a better way to write, "I ran or walked one hour every morning," indicating that he wishes to convey that he alternates between running and walking throughout that hour, walking and sometimes running during. There's a term for that. It's "interval training." So the better way to say it that I provided was, "I interval train one hour every morning," interval training being alternating between running and walking. If he chooses to do that as part of reaching a destination, like as how he goes to work or school every morning, that makes no difference.

Comment: interval train is very technical. I doubt a beginner would understand that.

Answer (score 2):

'On foot' includes both walking and running. See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20foot): 'by walking or running'.